# PyTorch Segementation Fault (core dumped) when moving Pytorch tensor to GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I have a machine with RTX 6000 ADA GPUs.

We used to have CUDA version 11.x and I used the following image:
`nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.04-py3`
(I use PyTorch 1.x).

However, it seems that drivers on our machine were updated to the following -

Driver information from nvidia-smi command:

`NVIDIA-SMI 535.161.07             Driver Version: 535.161.07   CUDA Version: 12.2`

Now I keep getting:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Whenever I try to move a tensor to cuda device.

I assume it's a CUDA version issue so I tried updating the image to:
`nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.02-py3`
that supports newer CUDA version, but the issue remains the same. Here is an example program that causes the issue:

```
import torch

tensor_cpu = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print("Tensor device before moving to CUDA:", tensor_cpu.device)

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")          
    tensor_cuda = tensor_cpu.to(device)    
    print("Tensor device after moving to CUDA:", tensor_cuda.device)
else:
    print("CUDA is not available. Cannot move tensor to CUDA.")
```

And the output is:

```
Tensor device before moving to CUDA: cpu
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I fix it? What is the correct image (with PyTorch 1.x) that I should use with my GPU?

Or is the issue be related to something else?

Comment: Can you provide your PyTorch as well as pytorch-cuda (cudatoolkit) versions?

Comment: @Ivan The versions are detailed here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_21-04.html

Comment: There are many possible versions on that page. Can you check both via conda?

Comment: Do you have multiple GPUs? If so, does the error present for all GPUs or just one?

Comment: @Ivan the link shows the image version I used - 21.04. It contains PyTorch 1.9.0a0+2ecb2c7 and NVIDIA CUDA 11.3.0.

Comment: @Karl I have multiple GPUs, it happens in all of them.

Comment: Can you print the value of `device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the CUDA toolkit version of your Pytorch installation is not compatible with the compute capability of your GPU. If you look into the [CUDA support table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported), you see that the `RTX 6000 Ada` has a compute capability version of `8.9`. This compute version only supports CUDA SDK versions **above** `11.8`.

| Compute Capability (CUDA SDK support vs. Microarchitecture) |
| --- |
| [image] |

However, the CUDA toolkit version you have installed - according to the image you are using - is `11.3.0` which is lower than the minimum supported version by a `RTX 6000 Ada`. In other words, you should use an image that comes with a higher CUDA toolkit version.

I looked at the available images, from release version [`22-09`](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel-22-09.html), and the shipped CUDA toolkit is equal to or higher than `11.8`. The first image that has this requirement is `1.13.0a0+d0d6b1f`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Segmentation Fault` generally comes from the unexpected memory access on native C.

It can be caused from Graphic Driver, Pytorch version, CUDA and cuDNN version compatibility, etc...

If all the compatibility are checked, try to investigate your GPU memory allocation, like memory leaking or OOM. Most of `Segmentation Fault` is caused from GPU OOM in my case as Pytorch sometimes cannot catch the out of memory.